# When can ı use -ing as participle or reduced relative clause?

Tags: participles, reduced-relative-clauses

As reduced relative clause: In fact, there is evidence suggesting that lower amounts are indeed efficacious.

As (present) participle: In fact, there is suggesting evidence that lower amounts are indeed efficacious.

Which one is correct?

Thanks for your answer in advance

Answer (score 1):

For this example, the first example is idiomatic (i.e. sounds natural) to me as a native (American English) speaker.

However, this is not a universal rule; there are verbs that could go the other way and would only sound right as a participle (e.g. damning evidence, surprising evidence, vindicating evidence, etc.)

Unfortunately, this appears to be idiomatic; I cannot formulate a guideline to give you (yay, English); I did try, but anything I could come up with I could also easily find an exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I also asked the same question on Reddit (r/EnglishLearning), and Question was answered like that: "Because "suggesting" is a non-standard adjective, and "suggestive," the adjective derived from the noun form, is standard. "There is suggestive evidence" is fine. Other words work differently. "There is corroborating evidence" is standard. "There is corroborative evidence" is not."

(https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/nktdhn/when_can_%C4%B1_use_ing_as_participle_or_reduced/)

For me, he/she is right. For you, is he/she right?